# parse Vector string into a String?

Tags: java, arrays, vector

How can i parse a Vector to a normal String?

i.e

Vector newfollowerlist = "name1, name2, name3, name4";

As soon i output the vector string it looks like this;

```
[name1, name2, name3, name4]
```

and i want to delete the [] of the line so i thought about parsing the vector string to a
normal String and delete the [] by:

```
String stringWithoutArraySymbols = String VectorHolder.replaceAll("[",""); 
String stringWithoutArraySymbols = String VectorHolder.replaceAll("]","");
```

How can i actually parse it or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Why on earth are you using a `Vector`?? This type has been deprecated for a number of decades. And what do you mean by "parse into a `String`"? You can parse a `String` into a structure or you can format a structure into a `String`. Please elaborate...

Comment: So what should i use else? i just need to store some names and output them without [].

Comment: Why not write your own logic to output the contents? Also, although an unlikely situation, your current solution would also edit any entry in the vector which contained a square bracket.

Comment: I would start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) and learn about collections.

Comment: @ james, thats actually no problem since usernames arent able to hold any []. i really just need to delete them and output em :)

Comment: @user3220962: iterate through the list, and append each name to a StringBuilder. Then call toString() on a StringBuilder. Shouldn't be more than 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight variation

```
String s = newfollowerlist.toString();
System.out.println(s.substring(1, s.length()-1));
```

You know the format of `newfollowerlist.toString()` so its easy enough to get your desired format. Should work if newfollowerlist is a Vector, List, Set or many other Collection types.

Comment: I would argue that encouraging the OP to use the `toString` method of `Vector` to "parse" a `Vector` is plain absurd. This answer is a dirty hack and the OP will find that in some random Java update this will break. Spectacularly.

Comment: The format is defined in the javadoc for AbstractCollection so officially part of the API. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()
Curiously the javadoc also mentions how its implemented, which is exactly the same algorithm as your solution, apart from a space after the comma.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned, do not use `Vector`. Read about the Java collections API.

I will use the `Collection` interface.

With Java 8:

```
final String joined = things.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

With Java 7:

```
final Iterator<String> iter = things.iterator();
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(iter.next());
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    sb.append(",").append(iter.next());
}
final String joined = sb.toString();
```