# How to remove the last comma when I print out the index of arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(words.length);
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(word.length);    
for(String x: list1){
        for(String y: list2){
            if(x.equalsIgnoreCase(y)){
               System.out.print(list1.indexOf(x) +" "+ ",");
            }
        }
    }
```

For this function, after run it, the output will be 2,5,7....9,
My question is how to remove the last comma?

Comment: I [wrote this exact code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22585042/2071828) a little while ago. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would print the comma at the start, something like this -

```
boolean first = true;
for(String x: list1){
    for(String y: list2){
        if(x.equalsIgnoreCase(y)){
           if (first) {
               first = false;
           } else {
               System.out.print(", "); // <-- or " ," if you prefer.
           }
           System.out.print(list1.indexOf(x));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to figure out when the last item has been printed.

You can either do this by iterating through the list first and figuring out where the last comma should be, or you can build the whole String using StringBuilder and then take the comma of when you're done.

Alternatively, you could put the comma *before* the word for every word except the first one.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is using loops with control over indexes:

```
int i,j;
for(i = 0;i < x.size();i++){
     for(j = 0;j < y.size() - 1; j++){
         if(list1.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(list2.get(j))) {
              System.out.print(list1.indexOf(x) +" "+ ",");
         }
     }
     if(list1.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(list2.get(j))) {
          System.out.print(list1.indexOf(x));
     }
}
```

Comment: i was originally thinking of this too, but suppose
list 1 = abcde
list 2 = abea
it will print out something like "0 ,01 ,4"

Answer (score 0):

Use `Iterator` to check if there still next elements in your list.

```
System.out.print(list1.indexOf(x) +" ");
if(itr.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print(" ,"); // print the comma if there still elements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, here it is in Java 8:

```
final String joined = list1.stream().
        flatMap(s -> list2.stream().filter(y -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(y))).
        mapToInt(s -> list1.indexOf(s)).
        mapToObj(Integer::toString).
        collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply remove the last comma after building the string

Build the string:

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
for(String x: list1){
  for(String y: list2){
     if(x.equalsIgnoreCase(y)){
        output.append(list1.indexOf(x) +" "+ ",");
     }
   }
}
```

Print with last comma removed:

```
System.out.println(output.substring(0, output.lastIndexOf(",")));
```

Comment: thanks for editing. will take care of comments next time

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.replaceAll(", $", "");
```

Comment: Please explain @Odaym

Comment: Use replaceAll to match a comma followed by 'end of line character' (ie the $ sign) replaceAll accepts regexes

Answer (score -1):

That's easy, do it this way:

```
Boolean b = false;
for(String x: list1){
    for(String y: list2){
        if(x.equalsIgnoreCase(y)){
           System.out.print((b ? "," : "") + list1.indexOf(x));
           b = true;
        }
    }
}
```